# Data type when registering Twitter developer account?

Tags: twitter

When registering the **Twitter** developer account, I saw the response as below

"**Thank you for your request. In order for us to review, we need a few additional details about your plans for the academic access to our API that you’re requesting. The information we need is listed below:**

**Will your research present Twitter data individually or in aggregate?**

**Please reply to this email to provide us this information. Please keep in mind, we need to receive the information listed above within 21 days, or Twitter will close the case without approving access.** "

I am wondering what I should reply the Twitter team because I did not fully understand what does "**individually**" and "**aggregate**" mean to answer properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means will your paper analyse each tweet individually and present the result or it will collect thousands of tweet and calculate some statistics based on them and present the **aggregated** (mean, median, std) result.